# Enforcing test execution before allowing Git commits

Tags: bitbucket, azure-devops

I'm working with BitBucket and VSTS to build a standard CI pipeline.
Development team works on a feature branch.  When their work is complete, they merge their code into development branch.

I would like a way to enforce a test execution prior to merging the feature branch into development branch.  Ideal situation would be something like this:

- The developer creates a pull request.
- The code review process is approved.
- The developer does SOMETHING, which triggers some process that merges the feature branch with the development branch (feature branch could merge into development branch, or a brand new branch is created with the two branches merged, or something else).
- The merged branch is built, deployed, and test executed against it.

  - Test pass: branch is merged into development branch.
  - Test fail: feature branch does not merge into development branch (if the branch is already merged into development branch, then the merged commit is reverted out of development branch).

The goal of this process is to keep development branch at a "good" condition. 
 Typically, the SOMETHING which triggers all this process is the act of committing (or merging) a code into the development branch.  The trouble with this process is reverting the code out of the development branch if the tests fail without loosing the code.  (It's possible that the merged branch has been deleted at this point).

Comment: VSTS has native support for Git repos with pull requests and branch policies enforcing successful CI builds prior to merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is build Pull Request feature in VSTS build, so you can create a new build definition with Build pull requests enabled, then the build will be triggered once a new pull request be created and match the target branch, you can check the build result in pull request in bitbucket.

[image]

You can define the policies through checklist: P[ull request guidelines for Bitbucket Cloud](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2016/01/26/pull-request-guidelines-for-bitbucket-cloud/).

BTW, the VSTS includes [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies) feature, so you can consider using VSTS repository.